# Images being frozen/delayed using VLCj and Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I'm making a mosaic for viewing videos. I build a JFrame with some components, including Canvas. I place an instance of a MediaPlayer on each Canvas and play the video. But I'm having problems with frame loss, delayed display and even complete freezing of images. Is there anything that can be done to solve this problem??

Mosaic:
[image: Images have been hidden to protect software integrity]

> (Images have been hidden to protect software integrity)

Code:

```
public class ViewerController {

    private List<EmbeddedMediaPlayer> playerList = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Canvas> canvasList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewerController() {
        gerarTela();
    }

    private void gerarTela() {
        String[] args = {
                "--rtsp-tcp",
                "--network-caching=1000",
                "--file-caching=300",
                "--clock-jitter=0",
                "--clock-synchro=0"
        };
        JFrame janela = geraJframe();
        var painelDaJanela = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 5));
        var factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            var containerDoVideo = new Canvas();
            containerDoVideo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JPanel painelDoContainer = new JPanel();
            painelDoContainer.setBackground(new Color(31, 27, 36));
            painelDoContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            painelDoContainer.add(containerDoVideo, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            var player = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
            player.setVideoSurface(factory.newVideoSurface(containerDoVideo));

            playerList.add(player);
            painelDaJanela.add(painelDoContainer);
            canvasList.add(containerDoVideo);
        }

        painelDaJanela.setBackground(new Color(31, 27, 36));
        janela.add(painelDaJanela, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        janela.setResizable(true);
        janela.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        janela.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                stop();
                super.windowClosing(windowEvent);
            }
        });
        janela.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void play(List<Camera> lista) {
        int limiteLista = lista.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (!(i < limiteLista)) {
                canvasList.get(i).setBackground(new Color(31, 27, 36));
            } else {
                Camera camera = lista.get(i);
                playerList.get(i).playMedia(camera.getUrl_video());
            }
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        playerList.forEach(MediaPlayer::stop);
    }

    private JFrame geraJframe() {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(d.width, d.height));
        jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jFrame.setIconImage(tk.getImage(getClass().getResource("/imgs/icon.png")));
        jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        return jFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to play 12 network streams via RTSP concurrently? Probably you don't have enough network bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I tryied with a better connection and it plays soflty, but there's some cameras that still freeze

Comment: Something that you can help me, @caprica ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how you can feasibly play 12 concurrent network video streams smoothly - did you work out how much bandwidth you have available and how much bandwidth your 12 streams use? Your network connection may be saturated.

Comment: I have 100mb here. The connection itself is consuming 20mb, so I have a good time off. Do you think it might be something in my code?

Comment: I noticed that the images do not freeze at once, but freeze over time. After 20 minutes, only two cameras are working ... Would there be any way to get feedback when the cameras freeze?

Comment: @caprica I m facing the same issue but using local ip cameras that enables streaming using rtsp